# Porque el loop del select me repite los datos solicitados y no me muestra los registros en pantalla Smarty

Tags: php, html5, formularios, php5, smarty

Necesito ayuda, porque no se a que se debe que al usar el `loop` con una variable en el `loop` del `section` me repite los valores y no me muestra los datos del registro en pantalla, el formulario consiste en que el usuario debe ingresar cuantos registros hará y así mismo él, al registrar los usuarios en la parte inferior se mostrará los registros realizados.

Espero no molestarles.

```html
<body style="background: #ebebeb;">

<form method="POST">
<fieldset>
    <div>
    <a href="index.php"><legend style="color: white; background: #BB1F35;">Formulario</legend></a>
    </div>
<div style="width:35%;background: #fff;border-radius: 5px; width: 50%;height: 50%;box-shadow:0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0, .5); padding: 30px; height: 100%;margin: 0 auto;">
    <div style="width:35%;">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="CantReg">Cuantos Registros Hará?</label>
        <select name="CantReg" id="CantReg" class="form-control">
            <option>  </option>
            <option>1 </option>
            <option>2 </option>
            <option>3 </option>
            <option>4 </option>
            <option>5 </option>
            <option>6 </option>
            <option>7 </option>
            <option>8 </option>
            <option>9 </option>
            <option>10</option>
        </select>
        </div>
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="nombre">Nombre(s): </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="apellido">Apellidos: </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellido" name="apellido" placeholder="Apellidos">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="TipoId">Tipo De Documento: </label>
        <select name="TipoId" id="TipoId" class="form-control">
            <option></option>
            <option>Cedula De Ciudadania</option>
            <option>Cedula De Extrangeria</option>
            <option>Tarjeta De Identidad</option>
            <option>Registro Civil De Nacimiento</option>
        </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="apellido">Documento: </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Id" name="Id" placeholder="Identifcación">
</div>  
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="salario">Salario: </label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="salario" id="salario" placeholder="Salario que devenga">
    </div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-primary" style="border-radius: 3px;">
</div>
</div>
</div>      
</fieldset>
</form>
<br>
<div class="form-group" style="width:100%;height: 100%;background: #fff;border-radius: 5px; width: 50%;height: 50%;box-shadow:0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0, .5); padding: 30px;margin: 0 auto; ">
    <p>Los datos ingresados fueron: </p>
<hr />
{section name = registro loop = $apellido} 
        Nombre: {$nombre[registro]} <br />
        Apellido: {$apellido[registro]} <br />
        TipoId: {$TipoId[registro]} <br />
        Id: {$Id[registro]} <br />
        Salario: {$salario[registro]} <br /><br />
        <hr>
{/section} 
    <!-- <p>cant:{$nombre|@var_dump}</p> -->
</div>
</body>
```

Aquí agrego el código `php` cabe recordar que esto lo estoy realizando con `smarty`

```php
<?php   

session_start();
    require 'Smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php';

    $smarty=new smarty;

    $smarty->template_dir = 'templates/';
    $smarty->compile_dir = 'templates_c/';
    $smarty->cache_dir = 'cache/';

    $salario=$_POST['salario'];
    $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
    $apellido=$_POST['apellido'];
    $Id=$_POST['Id'];
    $TipoId=$_POST['TipoId'];
    $CantReg=$_POST['CantReg'];


    $smarty->assign('cantidad',$_SESSION);
    $smarty->assign('nombre',$_SESSION);    
    $smarty->assign('apellido',$_SESSION);
    $smarty->assign('TipoId',$_SESSION);
    $smarty->assign('Id',$_SESSION);
    $smarty->assign('salario',$_SESSION);

    $pagina = $smarty->display("templates/index.html");

    return $pagina;
?>
```

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Gracias :D

Comment: Al parecer solo va a mostrar un registro

Comment: Esto claramente es solo un comentario y no una respuesta, por favor lee [answer]

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/168014)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo solucione hace varias semanas ya que en las sección del html donde obtenía los datos
no era un `{section}{/section}` si no que era un `{for}{/for}` y en la sección del php usé una variable global `$_SESSION` para que guardara los datos hasta que la sesión muera y de esa manera no se perdía lo registrado al darle al botón de submit.

El codigo del for era así:

```html
    <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Cantidad</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Apellido</th>
                <th>Edad</th>
                <th>Tipo De Identificacón</th>
                <th>Identificacion</th>
                <th>Salario</th>    
            </tr>   
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {for $foo =0 to $smarty.session.nombre|@count}
                <tr>
                    <th>{$cantidad}</th>
                    <th>{$smarty.session.nombre[$foo]}</th>
                    <th>{$smarty.session.apellido[$foo]}</th>
                    <th>{$smarty.session.edad[$foo]}</th>
                    <th>{$smarty.session.TipoId[$foo]}</th>
                    <th>{$smarty.session.Id[$foo]}</th>
                    <th>{$smarty.session.salario[$foo]}</th>
                </tr>
        {/for}
```

y el php era así:

```php
    if (isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['nombre']) && !empty($_POST['apellido']) && !empty($_POST['edad']) && !empty($_POST['TipoId']) && !empty($_POST['Id']) && !empty($_POST['salario'])){

        $_SESSION['nombre'][] = $_POST['nombre'];
        $_SESSION['apellido'][] = $_POST['apellido'];
        $_SESSION['edad'][] = $_POST['edad'];
        $_SESSION['TipoId'][] = $_POST['TipoId'];
        $_SESSION['Id'][] = $_POST['Id'];
        $_SESSION['salario'][] = $_POST['salario']; 

        $cantedad= count($_SESSION['edad']);
        $cantsal= count($_SESSION['salario']);

        for ($i=0; $i < $cantedad ; $i++) { 
        $resultado += $_SESSION['edad'][$i].'<br />';
        }           

        $resultadoedad=$resultado/$cantedad;

        for ($i=0; $i < $cantsal ; $i++) { 
        $resultado1 += $_SESSION['salario'][$i].'<br />';
        }           

        $resultadosal=$resultado1/$cantsal;

    }

    if(isset($_POST["eliminar_session"]))
    {
        session_destroy();

        header('Refresh:0');
    }   
    $cantidad = count ($_SESSION['nombre']);

    // $edad =array_sum($edad)/count($edad);,

    $smarty->assign('cantidad',$cantidad);  
    $smarty->assign('nombre',$nombre);
    $smarty->assign('apellido',$apellido);
    $smarty->assign('TipoId',$TipoId);
    $smarty->assign('Id',$Id);
    $smarty->assign('edad',$edad);
    $smarty->assign('salario',$salario);
    $smarty->assign('registrados',$data);
    $smarty->assign('cantidad',$cantidad);
    $smarty->assign('edades',ceil($resultadoedad));
    $smarty->assign('salarios',ceil($resultadosal));
    $smarty->assign('datos',$al);
    $smarty->assign('muestra',$mostrador);

    $pagina = $smarty->display("templates/index.html");

    return $pagina;
```

Hay unas cosas de mas por otras cosas que debía tener el registro pero de resto así era la manera correcta de realizar el registro.